# Windows 7 x86 program crashes when directory name is called BRU on Program Files

Tags: windows-7, crash

I have a problem with an application on Windows 7 (32bits).

The thing is this:

- Software path: `C:\ProgramFiles\BRU` (BRU.exe is the executable).

The application was working fine but today I try to open and it crash at the beginning. But if I change the folder `BRU` to something else, let's say `BRU1` then the application works again!

What is happening here?

Comment: Possibly it has some invalid settings either in the registry or a config file where the program is pointed to with that path, and that's causing it to crash?

Comment: The program doesn't write on the registry and in another configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have display of file extensions turned off, and the folder and file both have the name showing of "BRU", then Windows sometimes gets confused about the shortcut or references, not knowing if you mean the location or executable.

Comment: Even if i run the BRU.exe directly and not from a shortcut?

Comment: It all depends on the program & references it makes.  Do you have file extensions displayed?  Try starting it explicitly from the command line (cmd.exe) -- "CD \program files\BRU" then "BRU.EXE" (include the .exe explicitly.)